# How do I get categories links from links table where categories in one table matched links in another table"

Tags: mysql

I am new to programming and have run into a wall. I am trying to build a simple links site as a starting point to learn mysql and php.

I have two tables: categories - links

In the categories table I have a list of 35 categories. id (int) auto increment primary key and categories varchul

In the links I have id(int)auto increment primary key, link name, url and description.

I have gotten to the point where I can get the categories to list and create a url for each category using category?id=$id. but I cannot get the links associated with the categories to display by category. I either get all links or no links. I have used join, left join, right join, where links.categories=categories.categories . Nothing works. This is the code for getting the categories, I just don't know how to get the links for each cat. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
enter code here
    <? include "db.php" ?>
    <?php
    $id = intval($_GET['id']); // force user input to an int
    if(!empty($id)) // if the user input is not empty or 0
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id =  $id  LIMIT 1"; // attempt to select the row for the given id
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) // if the categorie was found
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch the resultset to an array called $row

    echo $row['categories']; // echo the categories field from the row
    // etc.
    }
    else
    {
    die('Error: Bad ID'); // the categories was not found
    }
    }
    else
    {
    die('Error: Bad ID'); // the id given was not valid
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between the categories and links in your design that is why you are getting no data back.

1. If each link can belong to only one category then add a categoryid field to the links table and then use that when joining between links and categories.
2. If each link can belong to more than one category, then you need a categorylinks table with categoryid and linkid columns, both of which are the primary key to prevent assigning the same link to the same category more than once. Then you can join using this table